# How to Keep Side Navigation Bar Hidden on Post Back in C# web forms application?

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I have a C# webforms application with a side navigation bar which is shown by default ,but on click of a toggle button it gets hidden and shown when toggle button is clicked again.

Javascript in my site.master page

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             if ($('#PanelState').attr('value') == 'false') {
                 $('#sidebar').addClass('hiddencol');
        }

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('active')){
         $('#PanelState').attr('value', true);
         }
        else {
         $('#PanelState').attr('value', false);
        }
    });   
    });
```

CSS

```
   #sidebar {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height:100vh;
    background: #158CBA;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -300px;
    }
.hiddencol {
    display: none;
}
```

aspx hidden field

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="PanelState" runat="server" value="true" ClientIDMode="static"   />
```

but after every post back the side navigation bar if hidden before  ,would not remain hidden

Comment: See the answer below. Since your attribute is not permanent it will go back to its original value after postbacks. Save the state to a part of the page that will retain its value after postbacks, like a hidden field. ASP.Net controls have 'View State', which is what keeps values the same after postbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a hidden field instead:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SidebarState" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to  use hidden field and i am still getting the same result.I have updated my question with the changes